# How to import CSV files with utf8mb4 using MySQL work bench

Tags: mysql

I've got a data set with English characters, Arabic characters, and emojis (there may be others, but those are the predominant classes I can think of). The encoding is `utf8mb4`. I wish to import this data set into my MySQL database. I was thinking of doing this just via the MySQL Workbench Table Data Import Wizard, but I noticed that

[image]

The Wizard strangely doesn't seem to allow one to import using just any utf-8 encoding, but it must be specifically utf-8 as opposed to utf8mb4, which I believe is creating a problem because I then get this error

[image]

I tried running a few Python scripts on the data to see if I could find any characters that didn't match UTF-8, but I got no errors.

Can anyone offer advice as to how to import the data if I can't use this Wizard? I assume the answer is just write a script to do so, which is fine, but I would love to know why the Wizard doesn't allow me to import more than just these encodings and if you could explain why its designed like this, that would be great!

Thanks!